# How to implement efficient UI updates while scrolling UIScrollView on iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I'm looking for a way to update UI elements while an *UIScrollView* is scrolled. There is the function `- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView` which is called multiple times per second and the method `- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView`which is called at the end of the scrolling (when there was a flick).

I have the feeling that doing updates in the `scrollViewDidScroll` is inefficient and the scrolling is not smooth anymore. What is the recommended way to do something like this?

Comment: You can have different approaches, but that will depend of the problem. what you think is the best "update rate" to your problem? do you really need update aways when scroll?

Comment: I'm updating the selected index of a tab bar based on the offset position of the scroll view. It should be realtime while scrolling. The method basically compares the scrollViewOffset against three threshold values.

Comment: Its possible to use an UIPickerView?

Comment: Of course, but that is not what I want to achieve. So I guess there aren't any other ways to do it